# Traverse '__dirname' in Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the parent of the current __dirname in my node application.

Here is my current line of code:

```
 mu.root = __dirname + '/theme';
```

Yet, I want to reach out of the current directory and into another one of it's sibilings.

Here is my directory structure:

```
lib
  this_file.js
theme
   theme_file.file
```

How would I go about doing this without having to parse the result of __dirname?

Comment: quick, [read the documentation!](http://nodejs.org/api/)

Comment: Please don't down vote my question without feedback.

Comment: @Nico thanks for the link. I must have missed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `../` to traverse to the parent of the current directory and `path.join` to resolve the path:

```
var path = require('path');
...
path.join(__dirname, "../whiceverdirectoryname");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `path.dirname(__dirname)`

Here's the [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p).